# How to get UserId from a PasswordReset token in ASP.NET Identity 2.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

To reset a password we need to know a UserId and pass it to the UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync method. In the Identity 1.0 it was possible to obtain UserId from the UserManager.PasswordResetTokens.Validate method ((UserManager.PasswordResetTokens.Validate(token)).UserId). Now it's gone and all existing examples telling me that I need to ask an user for username or email. This is not user friendly, I don't want my users enter username again if token is valid.

This is already established tradition in ASP.NET Identity - something that worked before is broken in the new release. Of course I can create my own combined token with embedded UserId, but why I need to do extra work? New releases should improve things, not make them worse.

Comment: You may want to familiarize yourself with [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/). The 2 in 2.0 signifies a major version change and accordingly may include so-called breaking changes. I wish I could help more but I haven't worked with Identity 2.0 yet. You may want to reconsider upgrading from 1 to 2, or take a different approach and completely replace your use of 1 with 2 instead of trying to tweak existing code. They may be two very different beasts.

Comment: @Jeremy Cook, I perfectly and clearly understand meaning of 2 in 2.0 and understand that it's a big change. My question is more like WHY they need that change and how I get that functionality back.

Comment: You can get it back by downgrading to version 1

Comment: Questions should include a question mark. This is more of a rant. Voting to close.

Comment: OP still has a good point. I'm scouring the web trying to figure out the same thing.

Comment: good question! I'm trying to figure out the same thing! Were you able to find a way to reset password with just a token?

Comment: @dima, no, I gave up. I just added email field into a form. I had no mood to deal with this mess which ASP.NET identity is.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was a security flaw that they fixed in Identity 2.

Answer (score 2):

Asp.Net Identity 2.x do not provide a way to find a user by a token created from GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync method.

You have two options:

1) Add the user id at the url you will send to the user. Ex:

```
var token = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(applicationUser);

var callbackUrl = $"/reset-password/?user={WebUtility.UrlEncode(applicationUser.Id)}&code={WebUtility.UrlEncode(token)}";
```

This approach is more user friendly. But I know people that says this is a security issue because anyone with the link could reset the user password.

2) Ask for the user name at the reset password page, as you did. Ex:

```
public async Task<YourResultModel> ResetPassword(ResetPasswordViewModel vm)
{
    // Your password validations...

    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(vm.UserName); 
    // could be FindByEmailAsync if your app uses the user e-mail to login.

    IdentityResult result = await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, vm.Token, vm.NewPassword);

    return YourResultModelFromIdentityResult(result);
}
```

Before choose between this two approaches you need to think about your specific scenario. For example: If your app uses the user e-mail as username and to intercept the token the "interceptor" needs to access the user e-mail box, remove the user id from reset password link will not improve the security of your app. Because who has the link already knows the e-mail of the user.